# Can もすこし遠かったら be used to mean "too far"?

Tags: pragmatics

Can もすこし遠かったら be used in the following sentence to mean if it is too far I will not go.

> もすこし遠かったら行かないんですが。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

もう少し means 'a little more', similar to もう一つ and the like meaning 'one more'. 「もう少し遠かったら行かないんですが」 means 'If it were a little farther I wouldn't go, though.'

Answer (score 2):

> **もすこし**遠かったら行かないんですが。

もすこし means もう少｛すこ｝し, and the interpretation of もう少し is perfectly written in Nothing at all's answer.

も すこし is a dialect for もう 少｛すこ｝し, and it may be commonly used in western Japan and at least in the Kyushu district.

Answer (score 0):

To say "if it is too far I will not go", you would say:

> 遠過{とおす}ぎたら行かないんです。

or you could probably just say it without the 過ぎる and the implication would still be that it's too far for you to go.

> 遠{とお}かったら行かないんです。

The も少し modifies 遠い, and indicates that the speaker is specifically stating that it would only take a little bit more distance for him/her to be unwilling/unable to go.